# Javascript Export CSV data URI is not displaying korean characters

Tags: javascript, csv, jscript, data-uri

I am using below code

```js
 var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,\uFFFE' + escape(str);
```

When i click on download CSV button in UI and the above code gets triggered and csv file will be downloaded.

The problem is  When i open the csv file , i see korean characters are not displayed properly and it is displayed as "%uBC29%uAC08"

**Questions**

- How do I display Korean characters in the CSV properly.

Answer (score 0):

The code is doing exactly what you programmed:

```js
var s = "방갈";
console.log(escape(s)); // %uBC29%uAC08
```

---

### UPDATE

Consider using `encodeURIComponent`:

```js
var s = "방갈";
console.log(encodeURIComponent(s)); // %EB%B0%A9%EA%B0%88
```

That looks like UTF-8 percent encoded.

From the Docs:

> ### escape()
>
> > Warning: Although `escape()` is not strictly deprecated
> >
> > ---
> >
> > … Programmers should not use or assume the existence of these features and behaviours when writing new ECMAScript code. …
>
> — [MDN JavaScript Reference - escape()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape)

---

### UPDATE #2

Consider using blobs instead of data uris:

```
var blob = new Blob([s], { type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8" });
var uri =  URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Frankly data-uris are obsolete.

For more information,

- [MDN Web API Reference - Blob constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob)
- [MDN Web API Reference - URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

Comment: I used  var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,\uFFFE' + encodeURI(str); 

and when i download csv i see that instead of 방갈로르,
 i see Î∞©Í∞àÎ°úÎ•¥ in CSV (So korean characters not displayed in csv opened in Excel)

Comment: should i use UTF-16 instead of UTF 8 in data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,\uFFFE ??

Comment: I even used encodeURIComponent and i see Î∞©Í∞àÎ°úÎ•¥  text in CSV instead of korean letters